# can i send message from chrome extension to java server ?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

so my question is I want build chrome extension to send message to java server should I use XmlHttpRequest API in chrome extension and java should be HTTP server?

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari all use the XMLHttpRequest2 object. While Internet Explorer uses the similar XDomainRequest object, which works in much the same way as its XMLHttpRequest counterpart, but adds additional security precautions.

You will first need to create the appropriate request object.

Check out the steps here: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/